# OpenGL ES texture atlas distortion

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to tile area with texture atlas and specific shaders but I get weird behavior on different devices.

Most of them *(Samsung Galaxy Ace, Samsung Galaxy Gio etc)* are ok, just bleeding occurs (hope I can fix it with half-pixel correction).

But *Samsung Galaxy S3* gets next with distance:

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzAqu.png)

(jumping from weaker to even worse distortion zone is also seemed, it happens exactly on regular atlas width or height passing)

- OpenGL ES 2.0, Android SDK are used.
- Atlas and texture part for tiling are both POT (1024 for atlas and 64 for texture part).
- Texture filtering doesn't matter: tried both *NEAREST* and *LINEAR*
- *drawable-nodpi* resources folder is used
- *mat4, vec2, vec4, sampler2D* precisions change does nothing

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to fix it?

Shaders:

**Vertex:**

```
    uniform mat4 u_viewmatrix;
    uniform mat4 u_modelmatrix;

    attribute vec4 a_position;

    varying vec2 v_texCoord;

    void main()
    {
        mat4 matrix = u_viewmatrix * u_modelmatrix;
        gl_Position = matrix * a_position;

        v_texCoord = a_position.xy;
    }
```

**Fragment:**

```
    precision highp float;

    uniform sampler2D u_texture;
    uniform float u_texpartx;
    uniform float u_texparty;
    uniform float u_texpartwidth;
    uniform float u_texpartheight;
    uniform float u_texwidth;
    uniform float u_texheight;
    varying vec2 v_texCoord;

    void main()
    {
        vec2 coord;

        coord.x = (u_texpartx + mod(v_texCoord.x, u_texpartwidth))/u_texwidth;
        coord.y = (u_texparty + mod(v_texCoord.y, u_texpartheight))/u_texheight;

        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, coord);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your images in `/assets`, not in `/res/drawable-nodpi`. I place all my content in `/assets` and have no problems with scaled, optimized or distorted in any other way PNGs.

Related question: [Android app loading images from /drawables-nodpi/ with scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963185/android-app-loading-images-from-drawables-nodpi-with-scaling)

You should check dimensions of your bitmap, however. If it is loaded with proper size then problem is not in scaled bitmap.

Also I'd recommend to update your shader - you should pass offsets to vertex shader and then pass final coordinates to fragment shader. They will interpolate correctly but you will have a whole lot less calculations in fragment shader (which possibly might affect precision on certain hardware, too).

Ultimately, you shouldn't make such calculations in shader at all - do this math in your Java code instead and just pass final coordinates for sampler into shader.

Comment: Unfortunately, migrating to _/assets_ did nothing too.

Bitmap size is exactly 1024*1024.

It is possible to tile every block separately, but would it be so efficiently as current fake-tiling tweak is?

Comment: OK then it might be caused by accumulated errors in calculations - you should pass ready calculated values into shader and see results. Have you tried using `highp` floats in vertex shader too? Or (the worst case) it is indeed bug of video driver.

Comment: I am afraid it is impossible to precalculate texture coordinates for fake-repeating outside the shader. Yep, highp in vertex shader is used now, but with no affect. Also, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787483/repeated-textures-are-severely-distorted-shaking-when-rotating-camera) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370074/opengl-es-2-0-texture-distortion-on-large-geometry-gl-repeat?lq=1) questions, but i can't sort out the suggested solutions

Comment: If you do use large values for sampling textures with `sampler2D` together with `GL_REPEAT` textures then you should clamp these values somehow. I've encountered similar issue caused by lack of precision of samplers on Tegra2 GPU.

Comment: Seems like the same issue, the difference is my custom shader for atlas part repeating instead of GL_REPEAT parameter, but it's facing up the same precision problems on large floating values. I tried to reduce "unused" integer fake-repeats values part and started using negative values to make floats closer to 0 for vertices' texture coordinates values initialization and now large geometries are looking much better. @keaukraine, thank you for suggested ideas and good advice.